# PS Script to print directory names if file type in it

Tags: powershell

I am looking for a PS script that checks for a certain file type(.err) in a folder's  sub-folders (depth -1) and if it finds at least one file with the required file type, prints only the sub-folder's name, without file patch or file name, e.g.:

```
[root folder]
[subfolder1]-has .err in it
[subfolder2]-doesn't have .err in it
[subfolder3]-doesn't have .err in it
[subfolder4]-has .err in it
[subfolder5]-has .err in it
```

Output:

```
[subfolder1]
[subfolder4]
[subfolder5]
```

I'm not good at PowerShell, so I only found how to list subfolder names which has .err files in it as many times as it has files inside.

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path C:\root -Depth 1 -recurse -filter *.err).DirectoryName | echo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after direction from @mklement0 my suggestion would be,

```
(Get-ChildItem (C:\root + "\*\*") -Filter "*.err").Directory.Name | select -Unique
```

Comment: Thank you. It's a quibble, because the performance difference probably won't matter here, but as a general point of interest: `Get-Unique` assumes pre-sorted input (or at least duplicates to be _grouped_, as in this case), which allows it to be much faster than `Select-Object -Unique`, which has to look at the entire input collection. Thus, along with pulling the `-Filter` argument into the wildcard path, I think the best formulation is ultimately: `(Get-ChildItem "C:\root\*\*.err").Directory.Name | Get-Unique`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question properly, this should do what you want:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Root' -Depth 1 -Recurse -Filter *.err -File | 
    Group-Object -Property DirectoryName | 
    ForEach-Object { ($_.Name -split '\\')[-1] }
```

It searches 1 level deep through the subfolders and if it finds files with extension `.err` (no matter how many files are in that folder), it outputs the subfolder name only once.

<sup>If you are on PowerShell version below 3.0, change the top line into

`Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Root' -Depth 1 -Recurse -Filter *.err | 
     Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer } |`</sup>

Answer (score 0):

*Update*: [Karthick Ganesan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57450289/45375) is the simplest approach.

---

Try the following:

```sh
(Get-ChildItem -Depth 1 -Filter *.err).Directory.Name | Get-Unique | Select -Skip 1
```

<sup>For brevity, I've omitted the `-Path` argument and also the `-File` switch that limits matching to *files*, as it's fair to assume that you won't have any *directories* named `*.err`.</sup>

- The use of `-Depth` implies the use of `-Recurse`, so the latter needn't be specified.
- `.Directory.Name` outputs the matching files' directory names as an array (via [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375), PSv3+).
- `Get-Unique` weeds out duplicates, which is necessary, because a given directory will be output multiple times if it contains multiple `*.err` files.
- `Select -Skip 1` (`Select` is a built-in alias for `Select-Object`) skips the first output object, because it represents the input directory itself (depth `0`).